# rails: how to divide data into separate td's after x records

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

## updated solution:

I changed things up a little bit from the accepted answer (which led me on the right track, so I'm not submitting a new one):

```
<table class="fixed">                                                                            
  <tr>                                                                             
    <th>Student Name</th>
    <!-- create as many <th> as there are evaluations -->
    <% @eval_count.times do |i|  %>                                                 
      <th>Evaluation <%= i+1 %></th>
    <% end %>    
    <th>Student Average <br />(for this goal)</th>

  </tr>                                                                           

  <% for eval in @evals %>                     
    <tr class="<%= cycle("odd", "even", name: "evals")%>">
        <!-- eval returns { s_id [eval],[eval]} -->
      <td><%= eval[1].first.student.name%></td> 
      <!-- in each student's row, print the score for each consecutive evaluation -->
      <% @eval_count.times do |i|  %>                                                 
        <td><%= eval[1][i].score %></td> 
      <% end %>
    </tr>             
   <% reset_cycle("evals") %>   
   <% end %>                                                                        
</table>
```

## end update

At the moment I have the following in my view (I know it's ugly, I'm only doing this so everything is on the same page while I test, I'll clean it up when it works!):

```
<div class="holder2 round">
  <% if @goal.avg.nan? %>
    <p>
      This goal has not been evaluated yet!
    </p>
  <% else %>    
    <%= render 'evaluations_by_goal' %>         
  <% end %> 
</div>
```

`_evaluations_by_goal.html.erb`:

```
<% ordered_evals_by_goal = @goal.evaluations.order("eval_number").all.group_by { |g| g.eval_number } %>

<h3>
The overall average for this goal is <%= @goal.avg %>
</h3>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Student Name</th>
    <th>Evaluation 1</th>
    <th>Evaluation 2</th>
  </tr>
  <% @scores = [] %>
  <% ordered_evals_by_goal.each do |number, evals| %>
    <% evals.in_groups(evals.count, false) do |group| %>
      <% group.each do |eval| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= eval.student.name %></td>
          <td><%= eval.score %></td>
          <td>**others here**</td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>   
  <% end %> 
</table>
```

## Edit:

so you can see the structure of the hash, `ordered_evals_by_goal` outputs this:

```
{22=>
  [#<Evaluation id: 1702, score: 4, created_at: "2013-08-25 11:00:58", updated_at: "2013-08-25 11:00:58", student_id: 22, goal_id: 28, eval_number: 22>, 
  #<Evaluation id: 1710, score: 3, created_at: "2013-08-25 11:01:08", updated_at: "2013-08-25 11:01:08", student_id: 23, goal_id: 28, eval_number: 22>, 
  #<Evaluation id: 1718, score: 3, created_at: "2013-08-25 11:01:15", updated_at: "2013-08-25 11:01:15", student_id: 24, goal_id: 28, eval_number: 22>, 
  #<Evaluation id: 1726, score: 3, created_at: "2013-08-25 11:01:21", updated_at: "2013-08-25 11:01:21", student_id: 25, goal_id: 28, eval_number: 22>], 
23=>
  [#<Evaluation id: 1734, score: 3, created_at: "2013-08-25 11:02:18", updated_at: "2013-08-25 11:02:18", student_id: 22, goal_id: 28, eval_number: 23>, 
  #<Evaluation id: 1742, score: 3, created_at: "2013-08-25 11:02:27", updated_at: "2013-08-25 11:02:27", student_id: 23, goal_id: 28, eval_number: 23>, 
  #<Evaluation id: 1750, score: 3, created_at: "2013-08-25 11:02:35", updated_at: "2013-08-25 11:02:35", student_id: 24, goal_id: 28, eval_number: 23>, 
  #<Evaluation id: 1758, score: 3, created_at: "2013-08-25 11:02:42", updated_at: "2013-08-25 11:02:42", student_id: 25, goal_id: 28, eval_number: 23>]}
```

## End edit

At the moment, it outputs this:

[image]

But where the student names begin to loop, i want the score data to go into the empty td so that the whole table is (in this case) 5 rows all together - one of table header and four of table data.  How can I do this?

Comment: i think it will be better if your fetch only desired records from database.

Comment: only desired table columns (just `score`), you mean?  At the moment I am fetching only the records I need - evaluations `belong_to` goal so that's easy enough

Comment: i don't know what associations you have in, and how duplicate records are coming, its better to fetch only unique records.

Comment: So you don't want to repeating students lines? You just wish to display one line per student with first and second column filled? E.g. Dax 4 3, Jenna 3 3, ...?

Comment: @jurglic, right, that's exactly what i want

Comment: Ok. Why do you use `.group_by { |g| g.eval_number }`? It doesn't seem you need it.

Comment: i've tried a lot of different ways to make this work, so partly it's a remnant of another attempt, but also my current code breaks if that's removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the wanted output, you can refactor your view code to this:

```
<% evals_by_student = @goal.evaluations.order("eval_number").group_by(&:student_id) %>

<h3>The overall average for this goal is <%= @goal.avg %></h3>

<table>                                                                            
  <tr>                                                                             
    <th>Student Name</th>                                                          
    <th>Evaluation 1</th>                                                          
    <th>Evaluation 2</th>                                                          
  </tr>                                                                           

  <% for student_id, (eval_1, eval_2) in evals_by_student %>                       
    <tr>                                                                           
      <td><%= eval_1.name %></td>                                                  
      <td><%= eval_1.score %></td>                                                 
      <td><%= eval_2.score if eval_2.present? %></td>                              
    </tr>                                                                          
  <% end %>                                                                        
</table>
```

Although, you should move the loading code (first line) across the controller into a model or other domain object. But that is another topic so I've left it as is in the question.

Comment: that works, thanks!  didn't know you could do `in x`, that's really helpful

Comment: Yes, I prefer the `for` to `.each` since it is nicely readable and feels more ruby. Glad it worked :)